# javascript - pass data from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have two functions. I want this function:

```
function indentSpace(s, n){
  return ((new Array(n+1)).join(s));
}
```

To get it's parameters from this function, while allowing this function to continue:

```
 function onHandle(line, report) {
  var input = $.trim(line);
  if (parensBalanced(input) == false) {
    indentSpace('.',input.length);
    controller.continuedPrompt = true;
  } else if (parensBalanced(input) == true) {
    controller.continuedPrompt = false;
    if (doCommand(input)) {
      report();
      return;
    }

    ...

  }
}
```

So that the 1st function gets used here, as the value for `continuedPromptLabel`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
controller = $("#console").console({
  continuedPromptLabel: indentSpace,
  completeHandle: onComplete,
  });
});
```

I've tried it several different ways, and it seems that once I get a value for `indentSpace`, it also returns that value in its containing function - and breaks other stuff.

Cheers!

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. `indentSpace` just returns a string, it doesn't **do** anything. But when you call it from `onHandle`, you don't use the return value. What does the `console` widget do with the `continuedPromptLabel` option?

Comment: Are you using this widget: https://github.com/chrisdone/jquery-console I don't see `continuedPromptLabel:` as an option.

Comment: You need to understand JavaScript Arrays. You are creating an Array that has `.length === 1` in `indentSpace`.

Comment: In the console, if the user types an incomplete expression and hits `Enter`  - I want the next line auto indented as many spaces as the input.

Comment: I took a look at the source code, and `continuedPromptLabel` is an undocumented option. But its value has to be a string, just like `promptLabel`.

Comment: @Barmar - yes. `continuedPromptLabel` is an option, just doesn't appear to be documented.

Comment: You can't provide a function for `continuedPromptLabel`. It has to be a string that you specify when initializing the widget. I don't think there's any way to change it on the fly.

Comment: @PHPglue - if the `input` is, say, 5 spaces, then `indentSpace` returns `.....` - I've verified that works.

Comment: @Barmar - it won't work if the function returns a string?

Comment: No. Something has to call the function, providing appropriate parameters. The widget doesn't call the option as a function, it expects it to be a string.

Comment: `(new Array(n+1)).join(s)` is like `[n+1].join(s)`, so you would have an Array with a single value (probably a number) that is being joined on the `s` delimiter.

Comment: @PHPglue: it looks misleading, but it returns a string: http://jsfiddle.net/wcfh1hdf/

Comment: Thanks all for the discussion. This is my first time working with javascript. @Barmar your tip in particular was very helpful. I ended up adding the function to jquery-console and was able to achieve the result I wanted.

Comment: Yeah, it joins to a String. What is misleading about that?

Answer (score 0):

So you want indentspace to essentially have a closure on its parameters from being called asynchronously from onHandle, such that onHandle is running freely, but then you want that indentspace with those parameters to be used elsewhere? I don't think that's possible.